# how to fill vector image separately for each path element with bitmap(or else) image? (android)

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, vector, path

I am developing an application that fills a map with pictures.
first I tried to crop map region by region and display image views in layout, but diplaying imageView is not easy..

Then I tried to fill region using svg image (transfer to Vector asset)

this is part of **ic_map_of_south_korea.xml**
and original svg image is [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Administrative_divisions_map_of_South_Korea.svg)

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="509dp"
    android:height="716.105dp"
    android:viewportWidth="509"
    android:viewportHeight="716.105">

<path
      android:name="Goseong"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:pathData="M340.083,66.939l13.334,-7l-8.334,-17.5l-1.333,-4.333l-7.167,-10l1.334,-1.833l-8,-14.167V8.939l-6.5,-8.333l-5.334,2.167L317.75,16.94l-1.167,7.833l-10.166,12.833l2.833,2l2.5,0.833l0.833,0.167l-1,1.833l0.667,4.333l5.5,-1.5l1,3.667l0.833,5.5l4.167,0.333l1,3.833l3.667,1l3.833,-1.833l2.167,2.5v5.5L340.083,66.939z"
      android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:strokeColor="#000000"/>


</vector>
```

this is clickListener in fragment (using this library : [RichPath](https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath) )

```kotlin
fun onClick() {
        val view: RichPathView = binding.icMapOfSouthKorea
        view.findRichPathByName("Goseong")?.setOnPathClickListener {
            Log.d("Goseong", "click")
        }
```

fill path is easy (using `fillcolor`) but I really don't know fill path with picture.

Comment: I don't believe you can fill a VectorDrawables with an image.  You'll likely need to use a different approach.

Comment: yes... I tring to use imageView instead. thanks :)....